# Way to overlay hover effect and href over DIV boxes?

Tags: html, css, hover, href, division

I have a particular page on my website (http://thefloodplains.com/TheFloodSharkMain.html) whereby I have 6 DIV boxes that I want to be clickable to take users to other areas of the site. So far I've been able to wrap the header text I have within the DIVs with links. However, I have been unable to wrap the DIVs, themselves, in links. Every time I put an a href="..." around the DIV boxes, nothing happens. This might have to do with the fact that images have been overlain on top of the DIVs, but I'm not exactly sure.

Additionally, since I want the DIVs to have links and be clickable, I would like them to fade a certain color (with translucent opacity) when hovered over. Basically, I want the boxes on this page to act the exact same as they do on my front page: .

What makes this hard is that I'm positioning it in a different area of the page, and the original code doesn't seem to work in this case. I've tried most everything I can think of without having to entirely retry and tear down all the code I've been using. As it stands, I cannot get the hover actions or links around the DIVs to react at all.

The code I have been working with to fade each DIV to a specified color (in this case an orange-yellow shade) looks like this:

```
.block:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  background: #FFE097;
  opacity: 0;
}
.block:hover:after {
  opacity: .5; 
}
```

Here's the overall CSS I'm working with

```
h2 {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color:#FF8B6F;
    text-decoration-color: #FF8B6F;
}
h4.shoe {
    font-size:36px;
    font-style: bold;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:'Buernard', Garamond, "Buenard", "EB Garamond",'EB Garamond';
    text-decoration-color: #00A5D1;
    color: #00A5D1;
    }
a {
    border-bottom: dashed 1px;
    text-decoration-color: #FF8B6F;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #FF8B6F;
    text-decoration: none;
}
u {    
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #00A5D1;
    text-decoration: none;
}
u:hover {
  Color: #FF8B6F;
  border-bottom: solid 2px;
}
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 960px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
.block {
  flex: 0 0 33.1%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #00A5D1;
  background-position: center center; /* center the image in the div */
  background-size: cover; /* cover the entire div */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #FF8B6F;
  /* align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; */
  text-align: center;
}
/* .block:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  background: #FFE097;
  opacity: 0;
}
.block:hover:after {
  opacity: .5; 
} */
x {
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;  
    font-size: 85px;
    font-family: 'Gentium Basic', Verdana, 'Slabo 27px', 'Vollkorn', serif;
    padding: 6px;
    margin: 6px;
    text-decoration-color:#00A5D1;
    color:#00A5D1;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #FFE097;
}
hr {
    border: none;
    height: 2px;
    color: black;
    background-color: #FFE097;
    margin-bottom: 33px;
}
p {
    color: black;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-family: 'Buenard', Garamond, 'EB Garamond';
    }
hr.two {
    margin-bottom: 16px;    
    }
ul {
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    padding-top: 12px;
}
br {
    padding-bottom: 6px; 
    }
li.pad {
        padding-bottom: 6px;
        margin-bottom: 6px;
    }
div {
    color: #00A5D1;
    padding-top: 14px;
    }
df {
   text-decoration: inherit;
   text-decoration: none;
}
.Row
{
    display: table;
    width: 100%; /*Optional*/
    max-width: 960px;
    table-layout: fixed; /* Optional*/
    border-spacing: 10px; /* Optional */
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
a.none {
    text-decoration: none;
    }
.blockx {
  background-image: url('DownloadMusic2.png');
  }
.blockx:hover {
  background-color: #FFE097;
}
.blockx:after {
  display: block;
  background: #FFE097;
  opacity: 0;
}
.blockx:hover:after {
  opacity: .5;
}
.blocky {
  background-image: url('EPKIcon2.png');
  background-position: center center; 
  }
.blocky:hover {
  background-color: #FFE097;
}    
.blockz {
  background-image: url('StreamAudio.png');
  }
.blocka {
  background-image: url('VideoStream.png');
  background-position: center center;
  }
.blockb {
 background-image: url('ContactIcon.png');
 }
.blockc {
  background-image: url('Handshake2.png');
  }
```

And here is the HTML of the web page:

```
<body>

<a class="btn" href="http://thefloodplains.com/"></a>  

<center><x>The FloodShark</x></center>
<br>
<center><df href="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/FloodShark-cropped-William-Luo.jpg" style="text-decoration: none;"><img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/FloodShark-cropped-William-Luo-1024x585.jpg" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 2px; padding-bottom: 6px" alt="floodshark-cropped-william-luo" width="856" height="480" class="alignnone size-large wp-image-228" padding-bottom="2px;" /></img></df></center>

<hr>

<p><b>The FloodShark:</b> A Florida-based producer/composer turned carnivorous, fresh-water tolerant, cold-blooded, cartilaginous predator surfing the sonic waves with an eclectic musical style</p>

<center><div class="container flex-container">

<a href="TheFloodSharkDownloads.html" title="Free downloads of The FloodShark's discography"><div class="block blockx"><a href="TheFloodSharkDownloads.html"><h4 class='shoe'><u>Downloads</u></h4></a></div></a>

<a href="EPK.html" title="EPK"><div class="block blocky"><a href="EPK.html"><h4 class='shoe'><u>EPK</u></h4></a></div></a>

<div class="block blockz"><a href=""><h4 class='shoe'><u>Stream Audio</u></h4></a></div>

<div class="block blocka"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCrcvj6Q-V4S-xad_Y_gPTFw/videos"><h4 class='shoe'><u>Stream Video</u></h4></a></div>    

<div class="block blockb"><a href="Contact-Social.html"><h4 class='shoe'><u>Contact</u></h4></a></div>

<div class="block blockc"><a href="Contribute-Support.html"><h4 class='shoe'><u>Contribute / Support</u></h4></a></div>

</div></center>

<br>

</body>
```

So basically I want to be able to use the boxes as is, but I would like to make it so that the entire DIV box for each box is a link, as well as fades to a shade of a specified color when hovered over. Thank you in advance for any and all advice!

Comment: Do you want your divs to act like anchors and open the same link that the anchors present in them are opening ?

Comment: Main problem with your code is that you are trying to add another anchor inside an anchor!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this html markup. Donot try to add anchors inside anchor ! it doesn't work.
Also you have missed styles for hover on blockz,  blocka, blockb and blockc. That is why no hover effect is shoeing on them.
See updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/owvs550p/4/

```
<a class="btn" href="http://thefloodplains.com/"></a>

<center>
    <x>The FloodShark</x>
</center>
<br>
<center>
    <df href="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/FloodShark-cropped-William-Luo.jpg" style="text-decoration: none;"><img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/FloodShark-cropped-William-Luo-1024x585.jpg" style="width:100%;margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 2px; padding-bottom: 6px" alt="floodshark-cropped-william-luo" width="856" height="480" class="alignnone size-large wp-image-228" padding-bottom="2px;" /></img>
    </df>
</center>

<hr>

<p><b>The FloodShark:</b> A Florida-based producer/composer turned carnivorous, fresh-water tolerant, cold-blooded, cartilaginous predator surfing the sonic waves with an eclectic musical style</p>

<center>
    <div class="container flex-container">

        <a href="TheFloodSharkDownloads.html" class="block" title="Free downloads of The FloodShark's discography">
            <div class="block blockx">
                <h4 class='shoe'><u>Downloads</u></h4>
            </div>
        </a>

        <a href="EPK.html" class="block" title="EPK">
            <div class="block blocky">
                <h4 class='shoe'><u>EPK</u></h4>
            </div>
        </a>

        <a href="" class="block">
            <div class="block blockz">
                <h4 class='shoe'><u>Stream Audio</u></h4>
            </div>
        </a>

        <a class="block" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCrcvj6Q-V4S-xad_Y_gPTFw/videos">
            <div class="block blocka">
                <h4 class='shoe'><u>Stream Video</u></h4>
            </div>
        </a>

        <a href="Contact-Social.html" class="block">
            <div class="block blockb">
                <h4 class='shoe'><u>Contact</u></h4>
            </div>
        </a>

        <a href="Contribute-Support.html" class="block">
            <div class="block blockc">
                <h4 class='shoe'><u>Contribute / Support</u></h4>
            </div>
        </a>

    </div>
</center>

<br>
```

CSS

```
h2 {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color:#FF8B6F;
    text-decoration-color: #FF8B6F;
}
h4.shoe {
    font-size:36px;
    font-style: bold;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:'Buernard', Garamond, "Buenard", "EB Garamond",'EB Garamond';
    text-decoration-color: #00A5D1;
    color: #00A5D1;
    }
a {
    border-bottom: dashed 1px;
    text-decoration-color: #FF8B6F;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #FF8B6F;
    text-decoration: none;
}
u {    
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #00A5D1;
    text-decoration: none;
}
u:hover {
  Color: #FF8B6F;
  border-bottom: solid 2px;
}
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 960px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
.block {
  flex: 0 0 33.1%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #9100ff;
  background-position: center center; /* center the image in the div */
  background-size: cover; /* cover the entire div */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #FF8B6F;
  /* align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; */
  text-align: center;
}
/* .block:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  background: #FFE097;
  opacity: 0;
}
.block:hover:after {
  opacity: .5; 
} */
x {
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;  
    font-size: 85px;
    font-family: 'Gentium Basic', Verdana, 'Slabo 27px', 'Vollkorn', serif;
    padding: 6px;
    margin: 6px;
    text-decoration-color:#00A5D1;
    color:#00A5D1;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #FFE097;
}
hr {
    border: none;
    height: 2px;
    color: black;
    background-color: #FFE097;
    margin-bottom: 33px;
}
p {
    color: black;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-family: 'Buenard', Garamond, 'EB Garamond';
    }
hr.two {
    margin-bottom: 16px;    
    }
ul {
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    padding-top: 12px;
}
br {
    padding-bottom: 6px; 
    }
li.pad {
        padding-bottom: 6px;
        margin-bottom: 6px;
    }
div {
    color: #00A5D1;
    padding-top: 14px;
    }
df {
   text-decoration: inherit;
   text-decoration: none;
}
.Row
{
    display: table;
    width: 100%; /*Optional*/
    max-width: 960px;
    table-layout: fixed; /* Optional*/
    border-spacing: 10px; /* Optional */
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
a.none {
    text-decoration: none;
    }
.blockx {
  background-image: url('DownloadMusic2.png');
  }
.blockx:hover {
  background-color: #FFE097;
}
.blockx:after {
  display: block;
  background: #FFE097;
  opacity: 0;
}
.blockx:hover:after {
  opacity: .5;
}
.blocky {
  background-image: url('EPKIcon2.png');
  background-position: center center; 
  }
.blocky:hover {
  background-color: #FFE097;
}    
.blockz {
  background-image: url('StreamAudio.png');
  }
.blocka {
  background-image: url('VideoStream.png');
  background-position: center center;
  }
.blockb {
 background-image: url('ContactIcon.png');
 }
.blockc {
  background-image: url('Handshake2.png');
  }
```

**EDIT**

Add the following styles for the hover effect to work properly

```
.block {
    position: relative;
}
.block:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    background: #FFE097;
    opacity: 0;
}


.block:hover:after {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The anchor advice worked and the boxes are now clickable. With that said, I'm still having trouble making the boxes highlight. Even using your code, the boxes don't appearing to be changing on hover - as if the images I'm using are still floating atop any changes. This is true for the boxes that I did have the hover effect on, as well as the ones that I don't.

Comment: So my changes can be seen here: http://thefloodplains.com/TheFloodSharkMain.html. I think that the images that I've chosen are overlayed atop the hover changes still. On my main page, http://thefloodplains.com/, an "after" hover effect was used, but I haven't been able to get it to work on these similar boxes on this page.

Comment: It does! Sorry for the late response, been on vacation. Thanks for all the help. You've been awesome.

Comment: One last question! So on my site I noticed that the last row of boxes runs beyond the borders that I wanted set. This can be seen at the page, here: http://thefloodplains.com/TheFloodSharkMain.html. I've tried editing the code, but haven't been able to adjust the second row to my liking. It also has the same problem sometimes when I shrink the size of the window. Any ideas?

Comment: Remove  'padding-top: 14px' that is applied on div tag